# Need to create contacts in "Directory" folder on Google Workspace

Tags: google-workspace, google-people-api

I need to share external contacts with my org so,, i tried to create the contacts in "Directory" Folder placed in admin contact console using people API. but, when i create the contact it's created only on "Contacts" Folder. please help me on this. i used the below code.

```
newContact = {"metadata": {"sources": [{"type": "DOMAIN_PROFILE"}]}, "names": [{"givenName": "John", "familyName": "Doe"}]}
results = service.people().createContact(body=newContact).execute()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory)

If you want to add people to the directory of your organization, you should not use the People API, but the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory).

To get this set up, you can follow the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python).

To add a new user to the directory, you would need to use the [`users.insert`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/insert) endpoint.

You would need to make sure that you are calling the endpoints as an Admin, or someone who has the needed permissions to create new users in your domain.

#### Reference

- [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory)
- [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python)
- [`users.insert`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/insert)

#### Edit

You can also follow instructions as laid out here:

> [Add shared external contacts to the Directory](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9281635)

Which mentions, among other options, the [Domain Shared Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts?csw=1)

Comment: Thanks for your help. i don't want to create user. i need to create the external contact only. "like shared contacts" pls suggest.

Comment: Hi, i'm not sure what you mean, can you say more about what you need exactly?

Comment: Yes.. i need to share the external contacts that not belongs to our organization to our users. so, i need to import the contacts to "Directory" Label using people API. (Pls find the image). but, the contacts created in "Contacts" Label.

Comment: Thanks. but, i don't know how to do this using python :(. please help me. https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts?csw=1 in this link i only found XML code.

Comment: I would like to help but that would make this answer way too long. Better to ask a new question with a specific question on how to use the GData APIs (which also support JSON now along with XML)

Comment: @iansedano the only applicable part of your answer is after "Edit". Everything before that is not relevant to the OP's question and should be removed. These are two completely separate APIs.